# Is Bitgert the fastest and scalable blockchain ecosystem ever?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Recently I happened to know that Bitgert will be the future of ideal blockchain network because it's the fastest and provides zero-gas fee.
Is this true? Bitgert has 15 seconds average blocktime whereas Ethereum is 13 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessarily true. I have never heard of bitgert, the speed and zero gas fee almost mean nothing for the usefulness of a blockchain. The reason ethereum has such a dominant position, is the fact that everyone accepts it as the standard. Also, Ethereum development is very good with a great community. If speed and price of fees are the goal for you, it would be optimal to use a layer 2 solution such as polygon, which has inherited security from ethereum.